# 3.5 dodge charger 2010 sxt

Tags: brake-rotor

I seem to have to replace my rotors every 3 months I put new calipers on I put new rotors new brake pads new line the front arm lower rocker arm somebody told me that it could be my struts is my car sways around the road in my rotors keep getting warped does anybody know what it could be thanks sherry

Comment: Are you buying quality brand name rotors? One of the drawbacks of cheap rotors is the tendency  to warp. Look at the shipping weight of the rotors, then buy the heaviest rotors you can afford. The heavier the rotor the more resistance to warpage.

Comment: Thank you..    I bought pretty decent ones.. not cheapest.. could my struts cause this to happen